# R: Reclassify a raster stack through the range of the quantiles of each layer. Generic quantiles function ; layer by layer

Tags: r, overlay, reclassify, function, rasterstack

I have a raster stack that contains terrain bends extracted with different neighborhood windows "crosc_nxn" (e.g. 3x3, 5x5, etc ...).

```
crosc_nxn <- raster::stack(path.files.list)
> crosc_nxn
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 170, 172, 29240, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 794418.4, 799578.4, 7400299, 7405399  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=22 +south +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names       : crosc_3, crosc_5, crosc_9, crosc_11, crosc_15
```

I want to create a new stack containing only the extreme values of each layer using two quantile ranges ( <= 0.01 or 0.99 >=).

```
out_prob <- function(x, min= quantile(x, 0.01,na.rm=TRUE),  max= quantile(x, 0.99, na.rm=TRUE)){ifelse(x <= min | x>= max , x, NA)}

range_calc <- calc(crosc_nxn, fun= out_prob)
range_over <- overlay(crosc_nxn, fun= out_prob)
```

It appears that `calc` applies the function to a certain pixel and traverses all layers to return the desired value. However I want my function to sweep all the pixels of the layer and then move on to the next one.  I'm surprised that `overlay` has returned the same result.

On the other hand when specifying the quantile for a certain layer the result is consistent with my query, in that layer where I expressed the interval.

```
    # calc quantile
    > quantile(crosc_nxn, c(0.01, 0.99), na.rm=TRUE)
                       1%         99%
    crosc_3  -0.001324438 0.001358304
    crosc_5  -0.000933790 0.000937456
    crosc_9  -0.000481476 0.000486876
    crosc_11 -0.000356400 0.000362014
    crosc_15 -0.000223900 0.000228338

    # explicit range in function    
    out_prob_ex <- function(x) {ifelse(x <= -0.001324438 | x >= 0.001358304, x, NA)}

    # generic 
    out_prob <- function(x, min= quantile(x, 0.01,na.rm=TRUE),  max= quantile(x, 0.99, na.rm=TRUE)){ifelse(x <= min | x>= max , x, NA)}

    quantile_generic <- overlay(crosc_nxn, fun= out_prob)
    quantile_explicit <- overlay(crosc_nxn, fun= out_prob_ex)

    # comparison using only the first stack layer
    par(mfrow = c(2,2))
    plot(outlier_generic[[1]], main= "generic formula")
    plot(outlier_explicit[[1]], main= "explicit quantile")
    hist(outlier_generic[[1]])
    hist(outlier_explicit[[1]])
```

[image]

I need a generic function for each layer, without having to express the quantiles one by one. I thought `overlay` would do this and I can not figure it out. Someone has an explanation to help me see the way out.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want an output stack of 10 layers. Each layer is a raster that only has a single value. out[[1]] is the 0.01 quantile of the values in crosc_nxn[[1]], out[[2]] is the .99 quantile of crosc_nxn[[2]], out[[3]] = .01 quantile of crosc_nxn[[3]] and so on?

Comment: Dear @Spacedman. I need  return a stack of 5 layers. One for each input of crosc_nxn (3x3, 5x5, ... 15x15). The output layer will receive two intervals of each input layer.

out[[1]] <- x [[1]] [ x [[1]] <= quantile (x [[1]], 0.01) | > = quantile (x, 0.99) ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets make a test raster to make it easy to see what's going on:

```
> r = raster(matrix(1:100,10,10))
> plot(r)
```

[image]

The highest and lowest values are in the left and right columns, so we can see if we are selecting them properly.

This function takes a single raster and returns the parts of the raster that are outside the given quantiles, and NA elsewhere:

```
> extremes = function(r,q=c(0.01,0.99)){
        qua = quantile(r[],q,na.rm=TRUE)
        Q = r<qua[1] | r > qua[2]
        Q[Q==0]=NA
        r*Q
        }
```

It works by computing the TRUE/FALSE raster that satisfies the condition, replacing FALSE (zero) with NA, and then multiplying by the raster values. That gives NA where FALSE and `r` values where TRUE. Test:

```
> plot(extremes(r, c(.2,.8)))
```

[image]

I'm using narrower quantile bands so I can see what's going on. With only 100 pixels I wouldnt see much with a 0.01 and 0.99 level. This looks good so far. Now let's construct a test `stack`:

```
> s = stack(list(r,r*2,r*3,r*4))
> plot(s)
```

[image]

To apply a function layer-wise, loop over layers with `lapply` and stack the returned layer list:

```
> exs = stack(lapply(1:nlayers(s), function(i){extremes(s[[i]], q=c(.2,.8))}))
> plot(exs)
```

[image]

Which I think is your final answer, once you've run it with your desired quantile levels.

Comment: thanks @Spacedman. very correct.  Many thanks for your generous resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a more memory safe version of @Spacedman's `extremes` function

```
extremes <- function(r,q=c(0.01,0.99)){
    qua <- quantile(r, q, na.rm=TRUE)
    reclassify(r, cbind(qua[1], qua[2], NA))
}
```

Comment: Is the last `mask` step needed? The values in Q will be the values from `r` and the mask will do nothing...

Answer (score 0):

The question and the answers gave solution if anyone wanted to remove values that is within a set range in a raster or raster stack. So, I thought it is useful to modify the function that will do the opposite (i.e., keep values that falls in between a set range of values). This can be particularly useful for beginners trying to find a solution.

The solution below is based on answer given by @Spacedman

```
# make a new raster
r = raster(matrix(1:100,10,10))
plot(r)

# function to remove values outside of desired range
extremesOut = function(r,q=c(0.01,0.99)){
  qua = quantile(r[],q,na.rm=TRUE)
  Q = r>qua[1] & r < qua[2]
  Q[Q==0]=NA
  r*Q
}


plot(extremesOut(r, c(.2,.8))) # keep only values that fall between 0.2 and 0.8

s = stack(r,r*2,r*3,r*4)
exs = stack(lapply(1:nlayers(s), function(i){extremesOut(s[[i]], q=c(.2,.8))}))
plot(exs)
```